# Upgrading webpacker from 4.2.2 to 5.0.1 is no longer running yarn install before assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets, webpacker

After following each step in the [webpacker upgrading](https://github.com/rails/webpacker#upgrading) section, an upgrade from `4.2.2` to `5.0.1`, is causing `yarn install` to no longer be invoked during `rails assets:precompile`. This is causing front-end packages sourced from our `package.json` file to not be found during the asset compilation process.

This is highlighted when CI runs `rails assets:precompile`. Previously `assets:precompile` would run `yarn install` before compiling our `application.js` file. I've added the `--trace` flag and it runs as if it skips `yarn install`.

```
** Invoke yarn:install (first_time)
** Execute yarn:install
** Execute assets:precompile
rails aborted!
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'moment' with type 'application/javascript'
```

The same CI run with the older webpack version displays the `yarn install` output as expected. Has anyone run into this same issue when bumping to 5.x?

Comment: Maybe the changes to the yarn install task are affecting you. https://github.com/rails/webpacker/compare/rails:96af013...rails:8e8e745#. What is `NODE_ENV` in your app's context on your CI server? What does `yarn install --no-progress --frozen-lockfile` output?

Answer (score 2):

We are currently on Rails `5.2.4` which didn't have the yarn binstub. Webpacker `5.0.1`'s yarn install task calls the binstub which internally invokes `yarnpkg`. Without the presence of the binstub, the rake task would do nothing which is what we were experiencing. Adding the missing binstub solved our issues.

/bin/yarn

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
APP_ROOT = File.expand_path('..', __dir__)
Dir.chdir(APP_ROOT) do
  begin
    exec "yarnpkg", *ARGV
  rescue Errno::ENOENT
    $stderr.puts "Yarn executable was not detected in the system."
    $stderr.puts "Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install"
    exit 1
  end
end
```

Comment: How did you add the missing binstub? I'm facing the same problem...

Comment: @ManuelMeurer I recall it not being generated when I ran `bundle install --binstubs`. I believe I ended up yanking it from rails source. I attached the file to the answer. Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

Comment/remote the sprockets line from config/application.rb:

```rb
# config/application.rb

# Remove the line below
 require "sprockets/railtie"
```

You can also remove `config.assets ...` lines from all your `config/environment/*.rb` files:

```rb
# config/environment/*.rb

# Remove the following lines
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.quiet = true
```

These are no longer required with Webpacker and could also cause errors.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for responding. Unfortunately none of those suggestions apply :/. We have debug set to false and quiet is not present. We're also not requiring "sprockets/railtie".

Comment: Sprockets is definitely being required if it's raising a Sprockets exception.

Comment: We haven't fully removed dependency on sprockets. Only part of our assets are being bundled with webpack. This has been working fine up until webpacker v5.